# .Net AdControl In Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, ads

Can I embed advertisement .Net `AdControl` in my c# windows application? I read that it's possible in c#/.xaml, windows 8 but i need it in my winform. Anu help appreciated!..

Answer (score 0):

What kind of advertisement do you need ? Do you need to monetize your application ,

Hope this helps ...

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-113